# Is the ether rewarded specified by the Ethereum client?

Tags: mining, evm, validators, homestead

So, the amount of Ether or Wei a validator or miner (ETH1.0) is rewarded, is it specified on the Ethereum client you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the amount of Ether or Wei that a validator or miner is rewarded is determined by the Ethereum protocol and is not specified by the Ethereum client itself.  The Ethereum protocol includes rules for block rewards, transaction fees, and other incentives that validators or miners receive for their participation in the network.

Comment: Is there a way to find it out ?

Comment: https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/incentives/rewards/ 
Is this helpful?

Comment: very helpful, thanks!